# Implementing Critical section using GCD in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch

I have a really heavy task to perform, and I dont want to block the main thread. So I'm starting a **separate Concurrent queue** for it. There can be 4 instances of the said task.

```
-(dispatch_queue_t)getConcurrentQueue
{
    if(concurrentQueue == nil)
    {
        concurrentQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.myself.HeavyTask", DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT);
    }
    return concurrentQueue;
}
```

Now to start the heavy task I have -

```
-(void)beginTask
{
      //.....
      //.....
        __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
        dispatch_queue_t queue = [self getConcurrentQueue];
        dispatch_async(queue, ^{
            [weakSelf heavyTask];
        });
}
```

Now the method heavyTask goes like this --

```
-(void)heavyTask
{
     //...
     dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_current_queue(), ^{
     // Initialising code for heavy task
     // This is the critical section. Only one of the 4 concurrent threads can enter this at a time
     }
     //....

     while(condition)
     {
        // Perform meat of the task
     }

     //...
     dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_current_queue(), ^{
     // Teardown code. Freeing memory etc.
     // This is also a critical section.
     }
     //...
}
```

The initialising code and teardown code uses some 3rd party C methods which are not thread safe. So making them thread safe is not the scope of the question.

Now I've put the `"initialising code"` and and the `"teardown code"` within -

```
dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_current_queue(), ^{
}
```

My code is crashing and I'm getting error messages stating that there is insufficient thread locking around the critical section code.

I read that `dispatch_get_current_queue()` is not safe, so I replaced it with `concurrentQueue`. I also tried replacing with `dispatch_get_main_queue()`. Still the code crashes, complaining about insufficient thread locking.

**I know there is something wrong in my understanding of implementing critical section using GCD.**

**Can anyone clearly show me how to make my code work properly here??**

Side question -- **Can I use `@synchronized { }` blocks here??**

Answer (score 2):

There's a lot wrong with your code, including not adhering to naming conventions.

So basically, if you want to execute the same task *concurrently* with respect to each other, use the global concurrent queue to execute those tasks.

If you want to concurrently access shared resources from within these tasks (or from elsewhere), define a dedicated queue, say "sync_queue" where you exclusively access these resources. This "sync_queue" executes your "critical sections".

The "sync_queue" can be serial or concurrent.

If you use a serial queue, use `dispatch_async(sync_queue, block)` for *write access* and `dispatch_sync(sync_queue, block)` for *read access* to shared resources.

If you use a concurrent queue, use `dispatch_barrier_async(sync_queue, block)` for *write access* and `dispatch_barrier_sync(sync_queue, block)` for *read access* to shared resources.

Example:

```
// Read access using a serial sync_queue:
...
__block int counter;
dispatch_sync(sync_queue, ^{
    counter = _counter;
});


// Write access using a serial sync_queue:
...
dispatch_async(sync_queue, ^{
    _counter = counter;
});



// Read access using a concurrent sync_queue:
...
__block int counter;
dispatch_barrier_sync(sync_queue, ^{
    counter = _counter;
});


// Write access using a concurrent sync_queue:
...
dispatch_barrier_async(sync_queue, ^{
    _counter = counter;
});
```

Example for your "heavy task":

```
-(void)heavyTask
{
     dispatch_barrier_async(sync_queue, ^{
         // Initialize heavy task
         ...

         // Continue with the task:
         dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0,0), ^{
             BOOL condition = YES;  // condition must be local to the block (it's not a shared resource!)
             while(condition)
             {
                // Perform meat of the task
                condition = ...;
             }

             dispatch_barrier_async(sync_queue, ^{
                 // Teardown code. Freeing memory etc.
                 // This is also a critical section.
                 ...
             }
         });
     }
}
```

Comment: About the naming convention..if you're talking about naming the variable as serialQueue..that was a typo, sorry about that..anything else wrong in the naming convention?

Comment: No, I meant `getConcurrentQueue` which should be `concurrentQueue` ;)

Comment: thanks for the input @CouchDeveloper. My problem is that the  "heavytask" is to be executed in parallel by 4 threads. And the init and destroy code within the complete method is the critical section, so only 1 of the 4 threads should be executing it at a given time. How can this be done using GCD?

Comment: @TusharKoul As noted in my answer: given, your task is a block: execute the block(s) on the "global concurrent queue"; within that block, execute the "critical sections" on the shared sync_queue (distinguish read and write access). Note: you *can* use dispatch_**sync** (instead of **async**) when executing a few statements AND if those don't introduce a deadlock, AND if this simplifies your code.

Comment: just one clarification...the `while(condition)` and the `teardown` are _inside_ the outer `dispatch_barrier_async` block??

Comment: @TusharKoul In my added example, the `while` block gets executed on the global concurrent queue, where it is assumed that no shared resources will be accessed. The init and tear down code executes on the sync queue and concurrent access to shared resources is thread-safe.

Comment: what about the call to the method heavyTask. Should I simply call [self heavyTask] now? Or even that has to be in a dispatch block?

Comment: @TusharKoul As you can see, in this case, you can invoke the method from anywhere you like: the method itself takes care to dispatch different code sections to the corresponding queues.

Answer (score 0):

You called it "getSerialQueue" but really you are creating a "concurrent" queue in it. Try to fix it substituting DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT with DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL in getSerialQueue.

Keep in mind that:

> dispatch_sync means: I will wait here until this block finishes
>
> dispatch_async means: I will not wait

This is not related to concurrent or serial. If two tasks in a concurrent queue call dispatch_sync(block), 'block' will be executed concurrently.

Hope this helps.

Comment: yeah sorry about that...it was a typo..I renamed my function

Comment: in simple terms, there'll be 4 heavytasks in the concurrent queue, I want them to execute in parallel. The init and destroy portions of code need are such that, only 1 thread accesses them at a time. How do i achieve that using GCD?